# Куда выложить свой исходный код?

Tags: opensource

Необходимо выложить свой исходный код. Пару раз качал с `github`, только что-то не понимаю как залить туда своё. Есть что нибудь попроще?  Можно без социальных плюшек как у github. Мне они всё равно не нужны. Просто выложить код в открытый доступ и всё. Спасибо.

Comment: > просто выложить код в открытый доступ и всё.

zip + scp - положить на свой хостинг?

> только чтото непонимаю как залить туда своё

**что-то**, **не понимаю**

надо скачать гит, проинициализировать репозиторий (`git init` в директории), добавить все необходимые файлы (`git add .` в директории), закоммитить (`git commit -m "initial commit"`), добавить remote (`git add remote origin %link%`, где %link% - ссылка на репу на гитхабе), git push -u origin master - и мы в небе.  
Кстати, если просто создать репу на гитхабе, то там будет написана та же инструкция.

Comment: Или же создаете репу на гитхабе, делаете себе клона, копируете туда все файлы из проекта, делаете коммит и пуш.

Comment: Попробуйте http://code.google.com

А если один файл, то можно и в pasebin.com выложить.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я бы порекомендовал https://bitbucket.org/ - он поминималистичнее гитхаба и главное - там есть приватные репозитории. Но в гите все равно разбираться придется =)